# log4J2 to slf4j to log4j1 produces "No log4j2 configuration file found"

Tags: java, logging, log4j

We have added libraries that use log4J 2.X, but we are still using log4J 1.X (mainly because we have our own impl of some Appenders and Loggers).
I was told that the solution is to send log4J 2.X to slf4j (using log4j-to-slf4j, version 2.X), and then slf4j to log4J 1.X, using slf4j-log4j12, version 1.X.

This is what I have just done, but I still get this message:

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default
>   configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property
>   'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to
>   show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.

I was hoping that slf4j would use the "configuration" of log4J 1.X, and that log4J 2.X would use the "configuration" of slf4j, so I would not need to do anything except configure log4J 1.X, but it does not seem to be the case.

Do I now have to duplicate my log4J 1.X configuration for log4J 2.X, or is there some easy work-around for this issue? Could it be some kind of "ordering" problem (what runs before what)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude the dependencies to log4j2, the classes that your libraries depends on will be provided by log4j-to-slf4j.

Comment: Actually, my mistake was that I had added a dependency to log4j-to-slf4j in the "parent pom", but not in the pom of the actual application needing it (which, obviously you could not have guessed). But as you answer is still useful, I'll accept it anyway.

Comment: @SebastienDiot I don't quite understand what your meaning. Are you just add `log4j-to-slf4j` and `log4j-over-slf4j` in your child pom file?